# Gimp, how to save defaults on some tool preferences?

Tags: gimp

Every single time i have opened an image in gimp to scale it down, I did so by percentage. Yet, the scale dialog always open up in Pixels.

Is there any way to save/set some defaults of my own for those tools dialogs?

I've already looked on [`.gimprc` file](https://www.gimp.org/man/gimprc.html) but it will not affect specific tools' settings, just global ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available yet - a generic "save/restore dialog settings" is somewhere on the enhancements list, and usually those are done by people who want them and have the time and the skills to implement them (finding these three qualities with one person is rare).

For the specific case of the scale and similar dialogs:

The dialogs use the same unit as the image itself, and you can set the defaults for this in the preferences - but unfortunately, percent isn't available there yet.

One possibility to get this would be to do the necessary changes to the GIMP source code and contribute those to the project.